# counting specific dates in a group in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I think it is a basic Crystal Report question, but i cant find an answer.
Consider the following report sql data:

> ID | NAME | DATE_CREATE | DATE_COMPLETE
>
> 1  John White     05.11.2014      25.08.2014
> 2     John White      NULL                    22.10.2014
> 3     John White      05.11.2014      22.10.2014
> 4     John White      31.10.2014      22.10.2014
> 5     Andy Brown      05.11.2014      22.10.2014
>
> 6     Andy Brown      NULL                    NULL
>
> 7     Andy Brown      06.06.2014      NULL
>
> 8     Andy Brown      20.05.2014      25.08.2014

(Bummer, not a singles clue how to create tables here)

I need to group by NAME and count DATE_CREATE and DATE_COMPLETE within the specific date.

For example, for 05.11.2014 and 22.10.2014, i want to get the following result:

> John White 2 3
>
> Andy Brown 1 1

Sorry for the poor formatting! Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a group by `Name` and place `Name field` in your group footer. Then create 2 running totals, one for `DATE_CREATE` and another for `DATE_COMPLETE`. On the running total screen you will put where says Type of summary -> `count`, evaluate on use formula -> DATE_CREATE = your parameter(date that you want to evaluate) same for DATE_COMPLETE and reset -> on change of group and select your group by `Name`. Place this 2 running totals on you group footer as well and suppress details section

Comment: I am glad that I could do it.